# How to check if flask_sqlalchemy table is empty

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to check if table has any users in it in Flask_SQLAlchemy.

I've done that but it doesn't work. Else statement is executed every time on a completely new database without entries.

```py
def check_for_user():
    if User.query.all() is None:
...
    else:
        print("Nope, it doesn't work")
```